# Auth Token not included in CORS exploit

Tags: cookies, cors, same-origin-policy, same-site-cookies, cross-frame-scripting

I have found a CORS on a website but when I am trying to exploit it for a POC it is fetching all the cookies except auth cookies and due to that I am getting an error message to "User not logged In"

[image]

**CORS Exploit Request**